# move element up without causing an overlap?

Tags: css, padding, margin

I need to bring .post_entry(right side) up so that it's level with .post_info(left side.
When I attempted to do so using `#main .post_entry p {margin-top: -82px}`, I caused an overlap of images and text. How do I move the element up without causing an overlap?

Thanks.

My live site- http://whskytngfxtrt.com

[image]

Comment: That's one of the cleverest domain names I've seen in a while.

Comment: @BoltClock It's a creative studio website, you can't expect less, can you?

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas on how I can move the elements up?

Comment: For one thing, you don't seem to be using `<p>` elements correctly. I have a feeling you should group your post info and headline into a single element, and your post entry into another, then float these instead. Basically, the layout needs some re-thinking to do away with the esoteric margin issues you're currently facing...

Comment: Not really sure what's wrong with margin-top:-82px, could you provide a screenshot to tell us exactly what's the problem? :o

Comment: @BoltClock could you give an example? i've kind of had a feeling i needed to rework the structure, i just don't really know where to begin since i'm learning this as i go.

Comment: @andreas image uploaded to show overlap. basically i'm wanting to move the entire .post_entry up, not the individual elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are constructing two paragraphs inside `post_entry`, one for the image and one for the text. Instead of having two paragraph's, have one and put a break `<br />` between the image and the text. That will fix it.

You will still need the `margin-top: -82px;` for the paragraph.

I have made two jsfiddle's. The one below has two paragraph's - where the text disappears behind the image.
[**Broken jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/qP5RF/)

The second one below, has one paragraph with a line break between the image and the text...
[**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/Y65Cw/)

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating. I'm wondering, though, if Wordpress doesn't add the `<p>` on it's own? I've not added them anywhere, and in fact have a </br> separating the image and text. If Wordpress is adding the <p>, where is it and how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: As it turns out, WP does add in <p> and </ br> on it's own. I disabled it by using a plugin called TinyMce Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
#main .post_entry {margin-top: -82px}
```

???

Comment: doing that triggers the overlap seen in the attached image.